# call by refernce char 2 dimensional for string not working

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am unable to pass my strings by reference , no here I am using char 2-dimensional , I could have used string , but I want to do it with char array , In swap1 function swapping of strings take place and in swap 2 function swapping of integers takes place . swapping of string is not working. Thank you for help . Any good link to learn this will be appreciated.

```
void func(int *x,char (*y)[500]);
void swap2(int &x, int &y);
 void swap1(char *a,char *b);
 int main(void){
    char str[4][500];
    int a[4];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){       
        cin>>a[i];
        cin>>str[i] ;
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=3;j>0;j--){
            if(a[j]<a[j-1]){
                swap2(a[j],a[j-1]);
                swap1(str[j],str[j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap1(char *a,char *b){
    char *temp = a;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}
void swap2(int &x, int &y){
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

Comment: Well points for making the code as dense and unreadable as possible. White space is your friend when it comes to readability.

Answer (score 4):

You are not writing your pointer swap like your integer swap. In your integer swap, you correctly use references, but you did not for your character pointers. The missing `&` results in a no-op for `swap1`, since `str[j]` and `str[j-1]` would retain their original values after the call finishes.

```
void swap1(char *&a,char *&b);
//...
void swap1(char *&a,char *&b){
    char *temp = a;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}
```

However, `str` is not an array of pointers, but an array of arrays. To make your code work, you should change `str` to be an array of pointers.

```
char *str[4] = { new char[500], new char[500], new char[500], new char[500] };
//...
delete[] str[0];
delete[] str[1];
delete[] str[2];
delete[] str[3];
```

But this is a lot of bother, and you would save yourself a lot of grief if you just change your code to use `std::string` instead. Then you could just use the `swap` method.

```
void swap1(std::string &a, std::string &b);
//...
std::string str[4];
//...
void swap1(std::string &a, std::string &b) {
    a.swap(b);
}
```